# shell (bash) json integer showing up as string not integer

Tags: bash, shell

I have a rather idiotic problem I have been trying to solve for the past 2 hours. So, I have this simple structure:

```
i=1 && post_var='{"UserId": 345,"ArticleId": "'"$i"'"}'  && echo $post_var
```

I get:

```
{"UserId": 345,"ArticleId": "1"} # string "1"
```

What I want is (I need `int` not `str`):

```
{"UserId": 345,"ArticleId": 1} # int 1
```

How do I go about this? I have tried numerous solution (escaping etc) but none seem to work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```shell
i=1 && post_var='{"UserId": 345,"ArticleId": '$i'}' && echo $post_var
```

or safer version:

```
i=1 && post_var="{\"UserId\": 345,\"ArticleId\": $i}" && echo $post_var
```

Comment: oh my! genius stuff :p will accept answer in 12 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just break quotation ?

```
post_var='{"UserId": 345,"ArticleId": '$i'}'
```